# Can't Deploy - VM instance field blank in deployment wizard

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new - something just must be missing in my configuration...

Can't Deploy - VM instance field blank in deployment wizard:

The wizard is shown where I can't select from the drop-down menu.  I expected it to have the instance "instance-1" which I have created and activated on Google Cloud Platform

[image: Wizard is shown where I can't select from the drop-down menu - I expected it to have the instance "instance-1" which I have created and activated on Google Cloud Platform]

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the Wizard is unable to reach out to the list of VMs. This might be a transient issue that could be resolved by restarting your Visual Studio. If this does not work, check the permissions over the VM in the Cloud Console or reinstall the  Visual Studio extension.

Could note that your project is an APS.NET site. Another way to perform the upload, is the web deploy manager, that fits perfectly with a .NET site and a windows VM.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-web-deploy-handler

I am not pretty sure about performing this deploy on command line, since that the deploy-manager is more related to Docker images but maybe it could be useful for you.

https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/quickstart

Good Luck!